# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' [BeautifulSoup]

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I was trying to run a simple python file using BeautifulSoup when I received the following error message in Atom.

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'**

I have already installed BeautifulSoup using the following command in my Macbook's terminal.

```
$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

I want to note that I have both Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.8.5 installed. I looked at my installed modules, and I only see 'bs4' in the modules for python3 and not in python.

When I try to place ***scrape.py*** in Atom or PyCharm, both text editors say that the module **does not** exist. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

***scrape.py***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

***Traceback***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lyons/Documents/scrape/scrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
[Finished in 2.237s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the previous answers managed to fix my error, but an ugly solution that I found was to just add the following code to the start of the file.

```
import subprocess
import sys

def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", bs4])

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone runs into this - bs4 behaves unexpectedly when working with subprocess (my setup includes venv). What worked for me was a revision of the suggested solution:

```
def install_bs4():
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "bs4"])

try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
except:
    install_bs4()
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: This one was amazingly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to install in particular version of Python

```
python2.7 -m pip install beautifulsoup4

python3.8 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: In the first command I received a message saying, 'No module named pip.' In the second, it said, 'Requirement already satisfied.' It still does not work for me

Comment: if pip is giving error means you do not have python2 installed. If you have python2 install pip then and try again

Comment: I have Python 2 installed though. In the terminal if I submit the command 'python,' it opens a shell that says, 'Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)' at the top

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix-based system, try running from root:

```
sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: I am using a Macbook

Comment: I don't remember if Mac has a sudo but I believe it should (?) you should give it a try.